# Sorting using k stacks with operation poppush(original stack, adjacent other stack)

Tags: sorting

I've been trying to read about sorting algorithms on stacks optimizing the amount of push and pops. One of a number of related probems I'm interested in can be formalized like that:

There is a set of $k$ stacks containing $n$ stack items in total ($n>>k$). The stack items are numbered from $1$ to $m$ where $m < n$ (i.e. several items have the same number). It is given how many items are on each stack including their number and position on the stack. The stacks are arranged linearly so stack $i$ is adjacent to stack $i-1$ and $i+1$ for $1<i<k$. There is no pop or push or peek operation, the only operation on the stacks is a combined pop and push operation which pops an element from one stack and pushes it on a neighbouring stack without returning its value. What is the minimal amount of poppush operations needed to get all items sorted on a single stack and what is such a sequence of poppush operations?

An example problem instance would be: $3$ stacks, $5$ items numbered ${1,2,2,3,4}$ and the first stack is empty, the second has $(1,3,2)$ and the third $(2,4)$ (first number in sequence is on top). I don't know the optimal solution, an arbitrary solution would be

- initial ($(),(1,3,2),(2,4)$)
- poppush(2,1) ($(1),(3,2),(2,4)$)
- poppush(3,2) ($(1),(2,3,2),(4)$)
- poppush(2,1) ($(2,1),(3,2),(4)$)
- poppush(2,3) ($(2,1),(2),(3,4)$)
- poppush(2,1) ($(2,2,1),(),(3,4)$)
- poppush(3,2) ($(2,2,1),(3),(4)$)
- poppush(2,1) ($(3,2,2,1),(),(4)$)
- poppush(3,2) ($(3,2,2,1),(4),()$)
- poppush(2,1) ($(4,3,2,2,1),(),()$)

Probably I'm missing some terms for getting better search results, I assume such things have been studied extensively since problems like that occur in sorting physical items using a machine.

Comment: Interesting question. Your problem sounds like generalized Tower of Hanoi game where you start from an arbitrary state of a solution, so perhaps this is a direction to look in.